# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Still learning JS since I'm a noob so bear with me.

I have a web app with 2 circular SVG gauges that currently work and I receive this issue before users log-in.

My Problem: I get 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null" firing off like crazy 
for `pathElementTwo.setAttribute('d', describeArc(26, 0, arcTwo));` in console because the area where that specific arc only needs to load when users log in. This only fires off like crazy in console before login, after login it disappears.

How can I fix this issue so console doesn't fire off like crazy before users log in?

Any help is gladly appreciated. Thanks!

JS

```
function describeArc(radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
    // Helper function, used to convert the (startAngle, endAngle) arc
    // dexcription into cartesian coordinates that are used for the
    // SVG arc descriptor.
    function polarToCartesian(radius, angle) {
        return {
            x: radius * Math.cos(angle),
            y: radius * Math.sin(angle),
        };
    }

    // Generate cartesian coordinates for the start and end of the arc.
    var start = polarToCartesian(radius, endAngle);
    var end = polarToCartesian(radius, startAngle);

    // Determine if we're drawing an arc that's larger than a 1/2 circle.
    var largeArcFlag = endAngle - startAngle <= Math.PI ? 0 : 1;

    // Generate the SVG arc descriptor.
    var d = [
        'M', start.x, start.y,
        'A', radius, radius, 1, largeArcFlag, 0, end.x, end.y
    ].join(' ');    

    return d;
}

var arc = 0;
var arcTwo = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    // Update the ticker progress.
    arc += Math.PI / 1000;
    arcTwo += Math.PI / 1000;

    if (arc >= 2 * Math.PI) { arc = 0; }
    if (arcTwo >= 2 * Math.PI) { arcTwo = 0; }


    // Update the SVG arc descriptor.
    var pathElement = document.getElementById('arc-path');
    var pathElementTwo = document.getElementById('arc-path-two');

    pathElement.setAttribute('d', describeArc(26, 0, arc));
   pathElementTwo.setAttribute('d', describeArc(26, 0, arcTwo));

    }, 400 / 0)
```

HTML

```
<div class="ticker-body">
                <svg viewBox="19, -19 65 35" class="gauge-background" 
fill="none">
                    <circle r="10"/>
                </svg>

                <svg viewBox="-39, -39 700 75" class="gauge" fill="none">
                    <path id="arc-path" transform="rotate(-90)" stroke-
linecap="circle" />
                </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay-collect"></div>
                <div class="hot-offer-btn"></div>

<div class="ticker-body-two">
                        <svg viewBox="4, -19 65 35" class="gauge-background-
two" fill="none">
                            <circle r="10"/>
                        </svg>

                        <svg viewBox="-51, -34 450 75" class="gauge-two" 
fill="none">
                            <path id="arc-path-two" transform="rotate(-90)" 
stroke-linecap="circle" />
                        </svg>
                        </div>
```

Comment: That error means that `getElementById` is not returning the object. Could you post your html? And that second argument on `setInterval` probably shoudn't be a division by 0

Comment: please share the html

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Ask yourself why `pathElementTwo` doesn't exist yet.  Are you waiting till the DOM is ready?  If it is an external SVG, are you waiting for it to load before trying to access its DOM?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau LeBeau I need pathElementTwo to fire off only after users log in not before log in. That's my problem. That area is in a hidden div before login. How can I solve this?

Comment: @brk I added my HTML, let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: @J.Maria I added the HTML. Let me know what you think. I need pathElementTwo to fire off only after users log in not before log in. That's my problem. That area is in a hidden div before login. How can I solve this?

Comment: @J.Maria if (pathElementTwo == null) solved my issue! Thanks!

Comment: @brk if (pathElementTwo == null) solved my issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you just need to add something to short circuit the build if you aren't ready for it.

One simple way with the code you have would be to just `return` if `!pathElement`.

```
setInterval(function() {
  // Update the SVG arc descriptor.
  var pathElement = document.getElementById('arc-path');
  var pathElementTwo = document.getElementById('arc-path-two');

  if (!pathElement || !pathElementTwo) {
    return; // don't do the rest
  }

  // Update the ticker progress.
  arc += Math.PI / 1000;
  arcTwo += Math.PI / 1000;

  if (arc >= 2 * Math.PI) { arc = 0; }
  if (arcTwo >= 2 * Math.PI) { arcTwo = 0; }

  pathElement.setAttribute('d', describeArc(26, 0, arc));
  pathElementTwo.setAttribute('d', describeArc(26, 0, arcTwo));
}, 400 / 0)
```

Now, if `pathElement` or `pathElementTwo` are `null`, it'll just return out of the function and stop doing things.

I also pulled the variables up to the top of the function for two reasons.

First, it's just good convention to declare all variables for a scope at the top, for readability and to help avoid potential errors.

The other reason, for this case in particular, is so you can jump out as early as possible. No need to do the other math if we aren't going to be able to do anything with it.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works, however I need 'pathElement.setAttribute('d', describeArc(26, 0, arc));' to run before login. How can I make that happen?

Comment: 'pathElement.setAttribute('d', describeArc(26, 0, arc));' is where the first svg gauge needs to run before users log-in. How do I get that specific arc now to run without going crazy in console?

Comment: if (pathElementTwo == null) solved my issue! Thanks!

Comment: crap.. my window was cached and looked like it didn't work :/